# How to disable word stemming in SQL Server Full Text Search?

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I need to do a Full Text Search with NO word stemming...I tried to wrap the term I'm searching in double quotes, but no joy... I still get results like "bologna" when I search for '"bolognalo"'

Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

Switch from using [`FREETEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176078.aspx) to [`CONTAINS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx).

I assume that you're currently using `FREETEXT` because stemming is automatically applied to `FREETEXT` queries, whereas `CONTAINS` doesn't use stemming by default.

---

A second, inferior, option is to specify language neutrality in your `FREETEXT` query:

```
SELECT *
FROM my_table
WHERE FREETEXT(my_column, 'my search', LANGUAGE 0x0)
```

If you use this then no other language-specific rules will be applied either (eg, word breaking, stopwords etc).

Answer (score 2):

After too many days spend in try, finally
I can do this:
I recreate catalog setting the language to 0 (neutral)

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX ON table_name
(DescriptionField LANGUAGE 0)
KEY INDEX idx_DescriptionField
ON catalog_name
```

and after in each query with contains I set the language to 0

```
select * from table_name where contains(DescriptionField,'bolognolo',LANGUAGE 0)
```

Before I couldn't do this because I didn't do the first step

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe setting the language of the fulltextindex to neutral will do the trick...

(Though, then you'd never get stemming at all...)